# Confusion about Friedel sum rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body

In Mahan's "Many-Particle Physics" (3rd edition, page 197), the so-called Friedel sum rule is of the form

$$Z = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_l (2l+1) \delta_l (k_F) , \tag{4.72}\label{4.72}$$

where $Z$ is the charge on the impurity, and $\delta_l(k_f)$ is the phase shift in the $l$-channel.

Just by looking at the expression, I cannot see how it could be true.

The left hand side is the number of electrons you add to the Fermi sea, while the right hand side is the phase shift induced by the impurity potential at the Fermi energy. The two sides depend on completely different factors which can be adjusted independently.

Consider such a scenario. In a 3d free Fermi sea, I ramp up a local potential $V$. As I do not add any particle, $Z=0$. But the potential $V$ is arbitrary and the original Fermi energy is arbitrary. How could the relation hold in this case?